# android - inserting long into SQLite Integer field

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on an app and need some help. I have a table where I store some informations and another which has a reference. The column where the reference is made is named "COLUMN_MODULE_ID". In my DBHelper, I have declared it as an Integer. But the value I get (which is the ID from the other inserted table row which I get as a long type) seems to not get into the table.

If I put i.e. 600 hard coded into the column "COLUMN_MODULE_ID", everything works fine. But if I set the long value "module_id" hard coded to 600 and put the variable into the column, it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

edit:

Okay, after further inspection, I have the following code:

```
Uri moduleUri = mContext.getContentResolver().insert(DataContract.ModuleEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                moduleValues);

String moduleId = moduleUri.getLastPathSegment();

Log.v("Module ID: ", moduleId);

getQuestionsArrayFromJson(moduleName, century, moduleId);
```

Lets expect, that the Log says "Module ID: 887". My App doesn't work.

But if I add

```
moduleId = "887"
```

after

```
String moduleId = moduleUri.getLastPathSegment();
```

, the log says the same but my App works. I have no clue why but I think it must be some type thing.

edit #2:

So I came further to the point where the whole thing blows up. When I fetch my data from a JSON String, I implement it into a table, which works fine. However, I get the _id from the inserted entry, which inserts just fine, with the following snippet:

```
long moduleId = ContentUris.parseId(moduleUri);
```

so when I log the variable moduleId, it shows the right _id.

When I try to insert it into another sqlite table, it doesn't work.

```
questionValues.put(DataContract.QuestionEntry.COLUMN_QUESTION_NO, questionNo);
questionValues.put(DataContract.QuestionEntry.COLUMN_QUESTION_TEXT, text);
questionValues.put(DataContract.QuestionEntry.COLUMN_MODULE_ID, moduleId);

Uri questionUri = mContext.getContentResolver().insert(DataContract.QuestionEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                    questionValues);
```

I just can't access it from my app. If I change the code to have a fix number in it like:

```
questionValues.put(DataContract.QuestionEntry.COLUMN_QUESTION_NO, questionNo);
questionValues.put(DataContract.QuestionEntry.COLUMN_QUESTION_TEXT, text);
questionValues.put(DataContract.QuestionEntry.COLUMN_MODULE_ID, 555);

Uri questionUri = mContext.getContentResolver().insert(DataContract.QuestionEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                    questionValues);
```

I can access the module with the id 555 just fine from my app. So I think it has something to do with the type that the ContentUris.parseId gives back.

I can also put the 555 in a long or int variable and put the variable into the questionValues.

Any suggestions?

Comment: SQLite supports the data types `TEXT` (similar to `String` in Java), `INTEGER` (similar to `long` in Java) and `REAL` (similar to `double` in Java). All other types must be converted into one of these fields before getting saved in the database. SQLite itself does not validate if the types written to the columns are actually of the defined type, e.g. you can write an integer into a string column and vice versa.

Comment: thank you. I updated my question with some new informations.

Comment: Hmm but the first code snippet still shows a number in the log.

Answer (score -1):

Okay I figuered it out. My Code was fine. I had another problem, clearing the table everytime I fetched new data into my database. Bad mistake, sorry.